# How to synchronise my function calls to store data in a recordForm variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Below is my record-uploader.component.ts file. While calling the upload method, I want to store the location of my S3 bucket response to recordForm variable. The output from `console.log(this.recordForm)` returns the path as undefined. This might be due to the async calls in angular.

I want to store the location URL to my backend server, is there any way I can retrieve the data and use it?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-record-uploader',
  templateUrl: './record-uploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./record-uploader.component.css']
})
export class RecordUploaderComponent implements OnInit {
  recordForm: Record;
  selectedFiles: FileList;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private recordService: RecordService
  ) {
    this.recordForm = new Record();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  upload() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.recordForm.posted_by = this.dataService.getName();
    this.recordForm.path = this.uploadFile(file);
    console.log(this.recordForm);
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadFile(file) {
    const contentType = file.type;
    const bucket = new S3(
          {
              accessKeyId: 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID',
              secretAccessKey: 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY',
              region: 'YOUR-REGION'
          }
      );
      const params = {
          Bucket: 'YOUR-BUCKET-NAME',
          Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
          Body: file,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: contentType
      };
      bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
              return false;
          }
          console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
          return data.Location;
      });
  }

}
```

The Record.ts is as follows :

```
export class Record {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public title?: string,
    public type?: string,
    public edition?: string,
    public category?: string,
    public specialisation?: string,
    public path?: string,
    public posted_by?: string,
    public posted_at?: string
  ) { }
}
```

Comment: Where is class `Record` coming from?

Comment: Record is used as an entity for backend service @benshabatnoam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming the problem is due to asynchronous data. One workaround is make all the functionality that depend on an async data to also be async. We could use RxJS `Subject` to achieve it. Try the following

`uploadFile()` function

```js
uploadFile(file): Observable<any> {
  const result = new Subject<any>();

  const contentType = file.type;
  const bucket = new S3(
    {
      accessKeyId: 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID',
      secretAccessKey: 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY',
      region: 'YOUR-REGION'
    }
  );
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'YOUR-BUCKET-NAME',
    Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: contentType
  };

  bucket.upload(params, ((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
      result.error(err);                // <-- push error here
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      result.next(data.Location);       // <-- push value here
    }
  }));

  return result;
}
```

Then you could subscribe to the `uploadFile()` function to retrieve the data.

```js
upload() {
  const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
  this.recordForm.posted_by = this.dataService.getName();
  this.uploadFile(file).subscribe(
    location => { 
      this.recordForm.path = location;
      console.log(this.recordForm);
    },
    error => { 
      console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err); 
    }
  );
}
```